# javascript file talk to script in html file

Tags: javascript

Is there a way of calling a function that exists in a HTML file from a .js file?

Something like this:

HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javaFile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething() {
    };
</script>
```

javaFile.JS file:

```
htmlFile.doSomething();
```

? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly call `doSomething();`